# Show price with two digits after comma

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to show a price, calculated from two input fields, with two digit after the comma.
So far I got this:

```
var lAnzahl = 0;
$("#ArtikelTabelle > tbody").on("keyup", "tr > td > input.anzahl", function () {
    lAnzahl = $(".anzahl").val();
});

var lPreis = 0;
$("#ArtikelTabelle > tbody").on("keyup", "tr > td > input.preis", function () {
    var aa = $(".preis").val();
    var bb = aa.replace(",", ".");
    lPreis = parseFloat(bb);

});

$("#ArtikelTabelle > tbody").on("keyup", "tr > td > input.preis ,tr > td > input.anzahl ", function () {
    var lGesamt = lAnzahl * lPreis;
    var lAusgabe = lGesamt.toString().replace(".", ",");
    $("#gesamtpreis").empty();
    $("#gesamtpreis").append(": " + lAusgabe + "€");
    lGesamt = 0;
    lAusgabe = 0;
    });
```

I already get `lGesamt` calculated properly but it displays like this: *12,3 €*
How can I add the *0* to the second decimal place or restrict it to show only two decimal places ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is method [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
(lGesamt).toFixed(2)
```

Comment: `toFixed()` Round number.